# I tried to import a .jpg into the background of my JPanel within a JFrame in the environment Eclipse. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? 

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, jpeg

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;    
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.String;

public class Game extends JFrame
{
    public IntroPanel introduction;
    public InstructPanel instructions;
    public GamePanel gameboard;
    public ScorePanel highscore;
    public QuestionPanel questions;
    public AnswerPanel right;
    public FailPanel wrong;
    public Container c;
    public CardLayout cards;
    private boolean runStandAlone = true;

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Game gem = new Game();
    }

    public Game()
    {
        setVisible(true); // allows JFrame to be seen
        setSize(800, 800); // sets the size
        setTitle("Biopardy"); // sets the title
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE); // Closing is taken care of 
        // by the following WindowListener, there's no default close operation.
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() 
        { // lets the program run without having to import all WindowListener methods
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) 
            { // this gives the user a chance to stop the close operation
                int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you really want to quit?");
                if(response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) 
                {
                    dispose();
                    if(runStandAlone)
                        System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        });

        c = this.getContentPane();
        cards = new CardLayout();
        c.setLayout(cards);

        introduction = new IntroPanel(); // initializes new panel
        add(introduction, BorderLayout.CENTER); // adds the panel to the center

        instructions = new InstructPanel(); // initializes new panel
        c.add(instructions, "Instructions"); // string identifier (call on panel by using this name)

        gameboard = new GamePanel(); // initializes new panel
        c.add(gameboard, "Start"); // string identifier (call on panel by using this name)

        highscore = new ScorePanel(); // initializes new panel
        c.add(highscore, "High Score"); // string identifier (call on panel by using this name)

        questions = new QuestionPanel(); // initializes new panel

        right = new AnswerPanel(); // initializes new panel

        wrong = new FailPanel(); // initializes new panel
    }

class IntroPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    private JButton start, record, instruct;
    private JTextField username;
    private Image jeopardy;

    public IntroPanel(Image jeopardy)
    {
        setBackground(Color.white); // sets background color
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        this.jeopardy = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("jeopardy.jpg");

        start = new JButton("Start");
        start.addActionListener(this);
        this.add(start);

        instruct = new JButton("Instructions");
        instruct.addActionListener(this);
        this.add(instruct);

        record = new JButton("High Score");
        record.addActionListener(this);
        this.add(record);

        username = new JTextField("User Name");
        username.addActionListener(this);
        this.add(username);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String command = e.getActionCommand();
        if(command.equals("Start"))
            cards.show(c, "Start");
        else if(command.equals("Instructions"))
            cards.show(c, "Instructions");
        else if(command.equals("High Score"))
            cards.show(c, "High Score");
    }

    public void WaitForImage(JApplet component, Image image)   
    {
        MediaTracker tracker = new MediaTracker(component);
        try 
        {
            tracker.addImage(image, 0);
            tracker.waitForID(0);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException evt)  
        {
            evt.printStackTrace();   
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(jeopardy, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: thynoob, welcome to SO. You've posted what we consider a poor question: a giant block of code, no description of the problem, and no error message. Please put more effort into your question, taking these points into mind, and read this: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: oh sorry for the block of code that is really big...ill cut it down

Comment: May not be a real [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826324).

Comment: i have added this. in front of the initialization of the variable jeopardy but there is still the issue of my compiler saying that the constructor Game.IntroPanel() is undefined. I'm not exactly sure what that means...

Comment: look at your code carefully and compare it with the compiler error message. Hint: how many constructors has your IntroPanel class and what exactly are their parameters?

Comment: well theres one constructor in the beginning of the JFrame that has it ....but i think that is all o__o and i dont really understand the compiler error messages; thats why im asking for help..so yeah and...when i run the program, i get these errors: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The constructor Game.IntroPanel() is undefined

 at Game.<init>(Game.java:62)
 at Game.main(Game.java:34)
 <--- (what do these mean?) o__o

Comment: Repeating the hint: how many constructors has your _IntroPanel_ class and what exactly are their parameters?

Comment: im sorry i dont understand ur 'hint' :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I see is that it should be

```
this.jeopardy = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("jeopardy.jpg");
```

You're just setting the method variable.

Edit: Also you're calling the null constructor. Make sure you call the right constructor for your panel.